# MQ command or standard process to load xml in local queue

Tags: queue, ibm-mq

What is the command(or process) for loading a xml file in a queue. I am using Websphere MQ6 in AIX. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you modify a MQ Java sample (shipped with MQ) for this job. You will have to write piece of code to read the data in the XML file into a buffer and pass that buffer to MQQueue.Put method call.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. Is it same as message PUT if I take message content in single line(i.e remove all new line character in xml file)?

Comment: What you put into the buffer is up to you as MQ does not understand what is in the buffer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use File2Msg open source program found here: http://www.capitalware.biz/mq_code_c.html

As the file name states, it will put a file as a message on an MQ queue.